# How to "translate" variables in one data frame using a second data frame as a key?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two string variables, and would like to convert them to numeric values using a separate "key" data frame. The below example is simplified, but I need to be able to apply it to replace the contents of the V1 and V2 variables based on an arbitrary key that will not always be a=1, b=2 etc...

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(
    V1 = sample((letters), 10, replace=TRUE),
    V2 = sample((letters), 10, replace=TRUE)
)
key <- data.frame(letters, 1:26)
```

I need to reference the first element of V1 against the key, replace with the according value (e.g. a = 1, b = 2, etc.), do the same for the second element, and then when done with V1 move on and do the same for V2.

I've been struggling to work out a solution using lapply() and sub() but keep getting stuck because I can't see a way to pass the sub() function more than a 1:1 comparison. Is there a different function I should be using?

Forgive me- I'm sure the solution must be simple but I'm quite new to R still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches with `base R` to make it:

- using `sapply()`

```
x[] <- with(key, sapply(x, function(v) values[match(v,letters)]))
```

or

```
x <- data.frame(with(key, sapply(x, function(v) values[match(v,letters)])))
```

- using `as.matrix` (similar to the `unlist()` approach by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59350868/12158757))

```
x[] <- with(key, values[match(as.matrix(x),letters)])
```

Comment: Thanks! sapply worked like a charm. I wasn't thinking to write the function within it like that using match in the values column. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lookup table with `data.table` and then apply the mapping along the columns of your data frame with `apply`:

```
library(data.table)

key <- data.table(letters = letters, value = 1:26, key = "letters")
apply(x, 2, function(x) key[x]$value)

>
   V1 V2
1   y  a
2   d  u
3   g  u
4   a  j
5   b  v
6   w  n
7   k  j
8   n  g
9   r  i
10  s  o
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `unlist` and `match` in base R

```
x[] <- key$values[match(unlist(x), key$letters)]
x

#   V1 V2
#1  25  1
#2   4 21
#3   7 21
#4   1 10
#5   2 22
#6  23 14
#7  11 10
#8  14  7
#9  18  9
#10 19 15
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%  mutate_all(~key$values[match(., key$letters)])
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(
    V1 = sample((letters), 10, replace=TRUE),
    V2 = sample((letters), 10, replace=TRUE)
)
key <- data.frame(letters = letters, values = 1:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apply` with both row and column margins, e.g, `as.data.frame(apply(x, c(1,2), function(l) key[key$letters == l,c(2)]))`.